# How do I place a text entry in a colored frame in python using tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, tkinter

I am making a wireframing tool desktop application for MacOS in python with Tkinter and I have no idea how to have a text entry bar that I can put in a frame that has a background color of black.

I looked up how to try and do this task, but had no luck. I have also tried to ask my coding class teacher if he can help me with this, but he couldn't figure it out either. Can someone try to help me with this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1430x840")


def clear_entry(entry):
   entry.delete(0, END)

// here is the text entry
entry = Entry(root)
placeholder_text = 'Title'
entry.insert(0, placeholder_text)
entry.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: clear_entry(entry))


// here is the frame which I want to put it in
frame2 = Frame(root, width=1430, height=56, bg="#292E30")
frame2.pack()
entry.pack(side=TOP, anchor=N)


root.mainloop()
```

the end result of what I want, this is an edited image with Preview so I can show you what I want it to look like in the end.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your `frame2` up and have the entry master set to `frame2`. To acquire a fully stretched black frame, pass a few more parameters to your `pack` method:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1430x840")

frame2 = Frame(root, bg="#292E30")
frame2.pack(fill=X,ipady=15)

def clear_entry(entry):
    entry.delete(0, END)

entry = Entry(frame2)
placeholder_text = 'Title'
entry.insert(0, placeholder_text)
entry.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: clear_entry(entry))

entry.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=N)

root.mainloop()
```